# Allow/Deny Access by IP to a Virtual/PHP Generated URL in .htaccess Without Apache Config Access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, acl

I've been trawling around, and theres many similar questions/answers, but none that fit, Or I'm searching for the wrong things

I'm using a PHP CMS, that routes the urls `/admin/some-module`

The `/admin` folder doesnt actually exist, as everything routes through an `index.php` bootloader.

I'm trying to effectively achieve

```
<Directory /admin>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from <some ip>
</Directory>
```

However it is on shared hosting which we cannot change the apache config to allow this.

How can you protect a url by IP from the root `/public_html/.htaccess` with the above setup?

Comment: so you do have access to change "the root .htaccess"?

Comment: well by root, I've got access to `/public_html/.htaccess`

Comment: do you know what version of Apache you are running?

Comment: this site seems to have a tool to easily create what you need (also could serve as a good syntax reference): http://www.toshop.com/htaccess-generator.cfm

Comment: @JeffPuckettII its apache 2.2 I believe

Comment: @KorreyD that link doesn't solve this issue as it doesn't define the path you're wanting to protect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I'd do that in the index.php but in htaccess you could try this

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.5
RewriteRule ^admin/ - [L,R=403]
```